# need to selectively escape html entities (&)

Tags: python, escaping, html-entities

I'm scraping a html page, then using xml.dom.minidom.parseString() to create a dom object.

however, the html page has a '&'.  I can use cgi.escape to convert this into `&amp;` but it also converts all my html <> tags into `&lt;&gt;` which makes parseString() unhappy.

how do i go about this?  i would rather not just hack it and straight replace the "&"s

thanks

Comment: i guess the reason i say i'd rather not just use .replace() is i wonder if there is a smarter way to create the dom object. seems like it should be able to tell what's data (between tags) and what's not?

maybe a better example would be if there was an `<` in the data which should be converted to `&lt;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For scraping, try to use a library that can handle such html "tag soup", like lxml, which has a [html parser](http://codespeak.net/lxml/parsing.html#parsing-html) (as well as a dedicated html package in [lxml.html](http://codespeak.net/lxml/lxmlhtml.html)), or [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) (you will also find that these libraries also contain other stuff that makes scraping/working with html easier, aside from being able to handle ill-formed documents: getting information out of forms, making hyperlinks absolute, using css selectors...)

Answer (score 1):

> i would rather not just hack it and
>   straight replace the "&"s

Er, why? That's what `cgi.escape` is doing - effectively just a search and replace operation for certain characters that have to be escaped.

If you only want to replace a single character, just replace the single character:

```
yourstring.replace('&', '&amp;')
```

Don't beat around the bush.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make sure that you don't accidentally re-escape an already escaped `&` (i. e. not transform `&amp;` into `&amp;amp;` or `&szlig;` into `&amp;szlig;`), you could

```
import re
newstring = re.sub(r"&(?![A-Za-z])", "&amp;", oldstring)
```

This will leave `&`s alone when they are followed by a letter.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use an XML parser to parse data that isn't XML.  Find an HTML parser instead, you'll be happier in the long run.  The standard library has a few (HTMLParser and htmllib), and BeautifulSoup is a well-loved third-party package.